# Label by order in group

Tags: python, pandas

Having a small toy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'clients': pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']),
    'Price': pd.Series([1.0, 22.0, 15.0, 7.5, 5.0])
})
```

I would like to create a new label based on the order of prices for each client:

```
   Price clients new_col
0    1.0       A       1
1   22.0       A       2
2   15.0       A       3
3    7.5       B       2
4    5.0       B       1
```

Hope the example clarifies.
I can obviously sort the `dataframe` but I am unsure on how to translate the labelling. Row indexes are not affected by `sort_index`:

```
  Price clients
0    1.0       A
2   15.0       A
1   22.0       A
4    5.0       B
3    7.5       B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'clients' column and then call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on the 'Price' column passing in the [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas.Series.rank) method:

```
In [409]:

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'clients': pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']),
    'Price': pd.Series([1.0, 22.0, 15.0, 7.5, 5.0])
})
df['rank'] = df.groupby('clients')['Price'].transform(pd.Series.rank)
df
Out[409]:
   Price clients  rank
0    1.0       A     1
1   22.0       A     3
2   15.0       A     2
3    7.5       B     2
4    5.0       B     1
```

`transform` will return a Series aligned with the original df